# How can I run a program as another user

Tags: permissions, package-management

I'm having a problem with permission on Ubuntu.

I have a user **appuser** on my system it can run node, npm, etc,

But now I need to install net-tools package

This one: https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/net-tools

The problem is that I install it with

```
sudo apt-get update -y
```

as root user, since I do not have privilege as appuser.

And when I try to run it as root user for example command: `arp` it is working fine.

But when I want to run it as appuser it won't work, even when I add appuser to sudoers.

When running `arp` as appuser I get:

```
bash: arp: command not found
```

Comment: `-bash: arp: command not found` may just be because `/usr/sbin` is not in your regular user's `PATH`. Does `/usr/sbin/arp` work?

Comment: One answer to the question in the title is "with `sudo`", _e.g._ `sudo -u appuser apt show net-tools`.  Adding this as a comment rather than an answer, as it is not clear that the title question reflects what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes it is installed /usr/sbin/arp, Yes /usr/sbin/arp works if I run it with sudo, But is there any way I can run it without sudo, or is there any way I can install it in appuser /usr/bin isntead of root

Comment: @user4556274 Hi you are correct, but how could I run it without sudo ? I would just like to run: arp as appuser, instead of sudo appuser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have installed `net-tools` (as root), you should be able to run `arp` as a non-privileged user either by specifying it's absolute path, *e.g.*

```
/usr/sbin/arp
```

or by ensuring that it is in the `PATH` for the user; *e.g.* in the appropriate initialization file (`.profile` or the equivalent for your shell/environment), add a line such as

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin"
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much that was the problem when I added to PATH line to bashrc it worked

Comment: Put it is `~/.profile`. If you put it in `~/.bashrc` then it can grow`.

Answer (score 0):

- You should always use `apt-get` as root to install. This does not mean that only root can run the installed programs.
- `sudo apt-get update -y` does not install anything. Use `sudo apt install net-tools` to install net-tools.
- `apr` is in `/usr/sbin` this directory is not in a normal users PATH. You can add it to you path (edit `~/.profile`). or run it as `/usr/sbin/arp`.